# Access Pipeline Variable Attributes That Have invalid variable names

Tags: powershell, scripting, pipeline

I am writing a powershell advanced function that will take input from the pipeline. More specifically, I will be piping in from import-csv. The problem is the column headers to the csv file I am using uses syntax invalid to ps. Here is what my code is like

```
function my-function{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    params
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$true,          
                    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string]$Id = $_.ID,


        [(Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string]$IdRaw =  $_."ID(RAW)",
    )

    BEGIN{
         #Sets up a db connection
    }
    PROCESS{
         #Builds an insert query with csv members
    }
    END{
         #closes db connection
    }
}

ID,ID(RAW),Date Time,Date Time(RAW),Type,Type(RAW)
29874,29874,4/18/2012 23:58,41018.20753, Servername, ServernameRaw
```

When I execute this with my csv input, the value of $Id becomes 2905, while the $IdRaw variable takes on a string representation of the entire $_ hashtable. Just to elaborate any paramter with a valid name {URL, ID, Status} all work. Any that contain a space or (RAW) receive the entire $_ variable.

-Patrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#Edit to include updated code
$x=import-csv c:\temp\testinput.csv

function my-function{
 [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string]$Id,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [alias("ID(RAW)")][string]$IdRaw 
    )

    begin{
         #Sets up a db connection
         Write-Debug "Starting"
    }
    process {
         #Builds an insert query with csv members
         write-debug "IDRaw=$IDRaw"
    }
    end {
         #closes db connection
                 Write-Debug "Ending"

    }
}

$x | my-function
```

sample file contents

ID,ID(RAW),Date Time,Date Time(RAW),Type,Type(RAW)
29874,29877,4/18/2012 23:58,41018.20753, Servername1, ServernameRaw1
29875,29878,4/19/2012 23:58,41018.20753, Servername2, ServernameRaw2
29876,29879,4/20/2012 23:58,41018.20753, Servername3, ServernameRaw3

Comment: Thanks, that was my first instinct, but when I do it that way all variables with column headers containing valid variable names function properly, while the ones with invalid names that I reference in quotations do not. When I run the example above, $Id takes on 2905 while the value of $IdRaw = $$_."Id(RAW)" becomes a hashtable of all the pipline input. Am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: I've never had issues like that using quoted property names (and I've done it a bunch).  Can you edit your post to include a few rows of the file?

Comment: I can add more code to begin process and end methods if necessary.

Comment: I really meant the csv file, since it's where the problem is coming from (I think).

Comment: The file has more columns but follow the same scheme, and also, If I do an import-csv from the powershell console I can maniputlate the imported objects with quoted properties just fine, it only screws up in the function

Comment: I think there are a couple of issues.  First, are you using powershell 3.0?  Second, it doesn't look like you're using the parameter attributes correctly to pull in pipeline data.  I'll have to play a bit to see if I can get a parameter to map to a "funky" property name.

Comment: Umm no, im using 2.0. Ill also spend some time making sure Im following best practice for pipeline input.

Comment: Fixed lots of issues with the parameter attributes.  Main "fix" was to use the alias attribute to map the ID(Raw) to the IDRaw parameter.  Added write-debug to the function to make it easier to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I was asking about 3.0 because a feature of 3.0 is that you can access properties of all members of a collection with simple dot notation.  That wasn't what was going on here.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks it works in my code too, looks like I need to brush up on my understanding of params